# Prove validation of if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{x_n\} = a$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{|x_n|\} = |a|$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Given a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\{x_n\} = a
> $$
>   Prove that $\{|x_n|\}$ is also convergent and:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\{|x_n|\} = |a|
> $$

I've started with the definition. If limit of $x_n$ exists then for some $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that:
$$
|x_n - a| < \varepsilon
$$

Now consider the sequence involving absolute values. If it does converge then:
$$
||x_n| - |a|| < \varepsilon
$$

But by triangular inequality we have that:
$$
|a+b| \le |a| + |b| \iff |a+b| - |b| \le |a|
$$
Let $c = a + b$ hence $a = c - b$:
$$
|c-b+b| - |b| = |c| - |b| \le |c-b| \iff \\
\iff||c| - |b|| = \pm(|c| - |b|) \le |c-b|
$$

So we have that:
$$
||x_n| - |a|| \le |x_n - a| <\varepsilon
$$

Thus going back from $\varepsilon$ definition to a limit we may conclude that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\{x_n\} = a \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\{|x_n|\} = |a|
$$

I'm not sure whether the above is a correct reasoning, so could someone please verify this?

Comment: The proof is correct. You may want to rephrase it as: "Since $|x| \leq |x-a|+|a|$ and $|a| \leq |x-a|+|x|$ we see at once $||x|-|a||\leq|x-a|$ hence if $|x-a|\leq\varepsilon$ we get $||x|-|a||\leq \varepsilon,$ that is, $|x| \to |a|.$"

Comment: @WillM. indeed, you hint makes it easier. Thanks for taking your time!